# Pandas panel count function causes TypeError

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas panel that looks like this:

```
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 4 (items) x 3 (major_axis) x 3 (minor_axis)
Items axis: 2015-09-16 to 2015-09-21
Major_axis axis: 0 to 2
Minor_axis axis: SOL to SAB
```

When I try to get the count on a certain axis using`panel.count(axis=0)`, I get a TypeError:

> TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the
>   inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to
>   the casting rule ''safe''

The problem appears to be with this line in the count function in Panel:

```
np.isfinite(values)
```

The strange this is I can enter`panel.sum(axis=0)/panel.mean(axis=0)` which results in the correct value of

```
   SOL MTN SAB
0   4   4   4
1   4   4   4
2   4   4   4
```

How can I rectify this or should I stick with me sum/mean method?